# how to display all the social accounts which have connected user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

how to display all the social accounts which have connected user?
Is it possible to make the display easier?

IN views:

```
  <%= twitter_profile(@user) %>
  <%= facebook_profile(@user) %>
  <%= linkedin_profile(@user) %>
  <%= google_profile(@user) %>
  <%= instagram_profile(@user) %>
```

Helper:

```
  def twitter_profile(user)
    user.twitter_profile ? image_tag(user.twitter_profile.profile_picture_url) : ""
  end
  def facebook_profile(user)
    user.facebook_profile ? image_tag(user.facebook_profile.profile_picture_url) : ""
  end
  def linkedin_profile(user)
    user.linkedin_profile ? image_tag(user.linkedin_profile.profile_picture_url) : ""
  end
  def google_profile(user)
    user.google_profile ? image_tag(user.google_profile.profile_picture_url) : ""
  end
  def instagram_profile(user)
    user.instagram_profile ? image_tag(user.instagram_profile.profile_picture_url) : ""
  end
```

Comment: You can simplify display with a partial. And DRY your helpers with metaprogramming too.

Comment: @ismail, you can try and see if the metaprogramming works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try **metaprogramming**, use this in your helper module:

```
%w(twitter facebook linkedin google instagram).each do |network|
  class_eval{
    "def #{network}_profile(user)
    user.#{network}_profile ? image_tag(user.#{network}_profile.profile_picture_url) : ''
    end"
  }
end
```

*Note: I do not recommend use of metaprogramming for the sake of readability and debugging.*